# Leer numeros de capturas de pantalla en bucle (a tipo float). Solucionar ruido existente

Tags: python, string, imagen, pytesseract

Ando programando en python y trato de conseguir un programa que sea capaz de leer y transformar a una variable tipo float un numero de una imagen como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay veces que hay una pequeña probabilidad que no lo lea bien y para eso he puesto un bucle que se ejecute hasta que lo consiga. Con el código que tengo hasta ahora el programa no acaba de transformar el string a tipo float (la variable torpedo se activa a uno y no debería). A ver si me podéis echar una mano.

Adjunto código a continuación.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import time
import string
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image

torpedo=0
i=0
while(i==0): #Ejecutese hasta el infinito
    flag=1

    while (flag):

        torpedo=0

        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(5, 708, 170, 32)) #Realiza captura de pantalla

    #guarda la imagen obtenida
        screenshot.save("TESEFOTO.jpg")

    # Read image with opencv
        img = cv2.imread('TESEFOTO.jpg')
    # Convert to gray
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
        kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
        img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
        img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
        cv2.imwrite("thres.png", img)
    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
        result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("thres.png"))
        os.remove("thres.png")
        #Escribe el resultado en string
        print(result)
        k=0
        dim2=len(result)
        #Recorre el string en busca de algun fallo en la lectura, si es asi reinicia el programa mediante la variable torpedo
        while (k < dim2 +1):
                if ((k == 0) or (k == dim2)):
                    a=result[k]

                    if ((a is not "1") or (a is not "2") or (a is not "3") or (a is not "4") or (a is not "5") or (a is not "6") or (a is not "7") or (a is not "8") or (a is not "9")):
                        print("FALLO AL LEER")
                        torpedo = 1
                        break
                else:
                     if ((k!='1') or (k!='2') or (k!='3') or (k!='4') or (k!='5') or (k!='6') or (k!='7') or (k!='8') or (k!='9') or (k!='.')):
                         torpedo = 1
                         break
        if torpedo == 1:
            continue
        flag=0 #Si no, se sale del bucle


    numero=float(result)
    print("Este es el numero en float: ", numero)
```

Comment: Bienvenido Droid Lopez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Con respecto a tu pregunta 1) Me resulta muy raro que tessercat lea bien a veces y a veces no un texto tan limpio y "perfecto" como el que muestras, de hecho, hice varios intentos y siempre leyó correctamente. ¿Puede que haya algún desfajase en la posición de captura y en algún momento se capture  "ruido" que dificulte el reconocimiento? 2) El código que estás usando para verificar es "raro", o al menos no lo entiendo, ¿podrías explicar exactamente que es lo que buscas verificar?

Comment: Perdón si he cometido algun fallo al formular la pregunta, tomo nota.

Comment: El lugar de la pantalla donde estoy tomando la imagen cambia cada cierto tiempo. Puede que tengas razón y podría ser que capture ruido en algún momento y por eso se quede bloqueado pero debería arreglarse en cierta manera al poner la variable torpedo=1 (volvería a tomar y procesar la imagen).

Comment: Lo que trato de verificar es que sea siempre un numero con la misma estructura que aparece en la imagen con 4 decimales. El primer condicional trata de evaluar si el primer y último digito son numeros si no es asi se pone la variable torpedo a 1. La siguiente condición evalúa el resto de digitos si son numero o un punto decimal. Cuando torpedo sea uno tendria que volver a ejecutar el resto del programa y así evitar problemas al traspasar el string a tipo float. Tampoco se si funciona mejor un "!=" o un "is not", por eso he puesto los dos probando en mis iteraciones.

Comment: Otro detalle, para hacer un bucle infinito puedes poner `while True:` y así no necesitas la variable `i `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay un enfoque que se usa mucho en python que dice que:

> *es más barato pedir perdón que pedir permiso*

Todo el código que estás usando ahora, para verificar si una cadena puede ser convertida a `float` es una forma de pedir permiso, mucho más fácil es convertir directamente la cadena a `float` y pedir perdón si esta no es un número. La idea conceptual, sería la siguiente:

```
numero = None
while numero is None:
  cadena = funcion_que_hace_ocr()
  try:
    numero = float(cadena)
  except ValueError:
    pass
```

Por supuesto, es la idea básica, deberías adaptarla a tu programa, lo cierto es que tienes un ciclo mientras `numero` sea `None`. En ese ciclo, haces tu lógica de captura y ocr, el resultado será `cadena` un string que intentaremos convertir a un `float`. Normalmente `float(cadena)` dispararía un error que nos detiene nuestro script,  si `cadena` no puede convertirse, pero usando un bloque [`try: ... except`](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/errors.html#errores-y-excepciones) capturamos el error sin detener el proceso principal, mientras ocurra el error no haremos nada (`pass`), si hemos podido convertir la cadena, entonces `numero` será un `float`, dejará de ser `None` y habremos salido del ciclo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, me funcionó!

Answer (score 2):

Aunque Patricio se me ha adelantado a dar la solución que yo iba a proponerte, muchísimo más simple que lo que estabas haciendo, aprovecho para resolver otras dudas adicionales que planteaste en la pregunta.

### ¿Por qué no funciona?

El error del código es la lógica de la comparación. Haces un `or` entre todas las posibles opciones, cuando debería ser un `and`, ya que si una cifra, por ejemplo es un '3' entonces no va a ser un '2' por lo que `a != '2'  or a != '3'` siempre va a ser cierta, puesto una de las dos será verdad (si es 2 entonces no es un 3 y si es un 3 entonces no es un 2).

Es un problema con las leyes de De Morgan, que resultan un poco contraintuitivas. Si para ver si algo es una cifra miras si es 1, ó 2, ó 3... para ver si **no** es una cifra has de mirar si no es 1, y no es 2, y no es 3...

En python esta comparación la puedes abreviar mucho más:

```
if a not in "123456789":
```

(no sé por qué has dejado sin verificar el cero, no sé si es un error o que realmente no te vale el dato si contiene ceros)

### ¿Se compara con `!=` o con `is not`?

En general, salvo una excepción que luego comentaré, debes usar `!=`.

La expresión `a != b` equivale a `not a==b`, y el comparador `==` sirve para ver si dos datos son iguales, y normalmente está definido para tipos de datos complejos en los que mirar la igualdad no es tan simple como comparar un valor con otro. Por ejemplo, si quieres ver si dos listas son iguales, debes mirar que tengan la misma longitud y que cada uno de los elementos de ambas sean iguales. El operador `==` está definido en Python para trabajar también sobre listas y sobre cualquiera de sus datos básicos, y puedes definirlo para que funcione sobre otros tipos de datos inventados por tí.

Por contra la expresión `a is not b` equivale a `not a is b` y aquí no se compara la igualdad de los datos, sino su *identidad*. Básicamente se verifica si `a` y `b` se refieren *al mismo dato* (o siendo más técnicos, a la misma posición de memoria). Por tanto si `a` y `b` son dos listas almacenadas separadamente en memoria, aún si ambas contienen exactamente los mismos valores `a is b` daría  `False` (pues no son la misma lista), mientras que `a == b` daría `True` si pese a no ser la misma lista, sí tienen los mismos valores.

El único caso habitual en que se debe usar `is` es si estás comprobando si una variable tiene el valor `None`. `a is None` será cierto si el valor de `a` es `None`, pues en ese caso `a` "apunta" a una dirección donde está guardado el valor predefinido `None`, que en python es un *singleton* (es decir, que todas las variables que valgan `None` apuntan al mismo sitio). En cambio `a == None`, aunque en general funcionaría también, podría fallar si el tipo al que pertenece `a` ha redefinido el operador de igualdad.

Comment: Abulafia te agradezco las correcciones. De nuevo muchas gracias!